# Strange MySQL error #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I received that error on query which definately has neither subqueries nor affecting more than one row:

```
UPDATE sl_requests SET price='55.00' WHERE request_id=5830;
```

> error: `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`

request_id is primary key, there is only one row with request_id=5830

I have no idea what's causing the error. Any ideas?

Comment: This kind of problem often relates to a trigger elsewhere.

Comment: what is the result of select statement with this request_id? Can you update with the table schema and relations.

Comment: @swayamraina the problem was with subquery in trigger

Comment: Personally, I would just delete the question, but feel free to answer it yourself, and accept that

Comment: I prefer to answer rather than delete. I searched through the web and didn't find answer so it may be helpful for someone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Strawberry pointed out the problem was with trigger. There was a subquery in trigger which caused issue.